# Datatype conversion in lookup transformation

Tags: oracle, types, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have lookup table with one string column and input column from source qualifier is decimal data type. I need to use these two columns in lkp condition. While doing this it is throwing invalid datatype error. So here i need to convert input lookup column datatype. Is anyother way to get this done

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input column in another column in an expression using the function below: `TO_CHAR(Your_Column)`, then link this new column to your lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The datatypes of the 2 columns need to be the same, otherwise how can you expect there to be any matches in the lookup?
You can either convert the string to a decimal or the decimal to a string, whichever is easier

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have converted all columns to decimal previously it doesnt worked because of size mismatch. It is expecting same size for both the columns using in lkp condition. Correct that now it is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an Expression transformation that will first transform your input to string then do the lookup after the Exptrans. Try this

[image]